# Can a partitioned CosmosDB / DocumentDB collection have fewer than 400 RU/s of throughput configured?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

***Update***: This question is now invalid as the events I'd thought happened didn't happen quite as I'd thought (see below for details). I'm leaving the question as-is though as the answers and comments may be useful to others.

I've created a collection via the Azure Portal, configured initially with:

- Storage Capacity: Unlimited
- Initial Throughput Capacity (RU/s): 2500
- Partition Key: `/PartitionKey`

Then through the .NET SDK I've changed the *Initial Throughput Capacity (RU/s)* to 400.

According to the *Scale & Settings* tab for the collection in the Azure Portal the value of *Throughput (400 - 10,000 RU/s*)* is 400.

**Is this a supported configuration?** I'm assuming this is a bug somewhere but perhaps it isn't? **What would I be charged for this collection?**

As an aside...

The *Add Collection* screen doesn't allow me to set the Throughput to 400 on initial creation but it seems I can change it afterwards.

[image]

***Update***: I think I've worked out what happened. I manually created a partitioned collection, then I forgot that my code (an importer/migration tool I'm working on) deletes the database and recreates the database and collection on startup. When it does this, it's created as a non-partitioned collection. Now that I've corrected this, I get the error "The offer should have valid throughput values between 2500 and 100000 inclusive in increments of 100." if I try to reproduce what I thought I'd managed to do before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not seeing a bug. You're attempting to set an RU range on a partitioned collection.

Single-partition collections (10GB) allow for 400-10000 RU.

What you're showing in your question is a partitioned collection, with scale starting at 2500 RU.

And you cannot configure a partitioned collection for 400 RU, whether through the portal or through API/SDK.

Comment: I don't think that it strictly true; See https://disqus.com/home/discussion/thewindowsazureproductsite/partitioning_data_in_documentdb/#comment-2637274475
That was from a different era, but the principle should still be the same. It's for testing only, though.

Comment: @David Makagon If you re-read my question you'll see that I have set the collection to 400 RU/s *after* creating it as a partitioned collection. What I'm not sure about, is what I've now ended up with.

Comment: What I'm saying is: you *cannot* convert a partitioned collection to non-partitioned. That capability doesn't exist. I have no idea what you ended up with but you can view your partition's RU setting in the portal after making your SDK call.

Comment: @DavidMakogon In that case I have ended up with a partitioned collection which currently has 1 physical partition and 400RU/s. According to the Azure Portal "Collection X has 1 physical partitions. Provisioned throughput is evenly distributed across physical partitions, 400 RU/second per partition." And that collection was created originally as a partitioned collection.

Comment: @tjrobinson Can you try scaling back up through the API and checking the storage metrics again? I'd be super curious to see what happens with the number of physical partitions assigned to your collection after you scaled back up to 2500 RU and then again to > 10K RU

Comment: I think I've worked out what happened. I manually created a partitioned collection, then I forgot that my code (an importer/migration tool I'm working on) deletes the database and recreates the database and collection on startup. When it does this, it's created as a non-partitioned collection. Now that I've corrected this, I get the error "The offer should have valid throughput values between 2500 and 100000 inclusive in increments of 100." if I try to reproduce what I thought I'd managed to do before. So @DavidMakogon is indeed correct.

Comment: @JesseCarter To try and answer your question, if I create a partitioned collection with 2500RUs, it has 10 partitions initially (1 document). If I increase to 10,000RUs or 100,000RUs the number of partitions stays at 10. I expect this would change if there were more documents.